# Unclear how to configure NServiceBus with Castle Windsor in ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus 3.2.7, Castle Windsor 3.1, and ASP.Net MVC 4. I am configuring Windsor currently with the Windsor Tutorial... [Windsor tutorial - ASP.NET MVC 3 application](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx)

I am unsure how to setup NServiceBus inside this configuration. I'd like to maintain the installer pattern, and I won't be running the host (I believe). Inside this solution is the host process that handles all the messages and it uses the typical Endpointconfiguration with Windsor which handles all the container registrations.

Having the web project send a message was an after thought and I'd like to not have to alter the way I have configured the web project to add NServiceBus in. If anyone can offer up an example of how to do this, that would be fantastic. I figure it would be in a facility similar to the persistence facility in the tutorial, but I am still a little unsure how to do this appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be rather simple.

Simply creating another installer class (since it seems the `CastleWindsorBuilder()` needed the container passed in. I had tried to create a facility and this was my problem.) I created an installer class like so:

```
public class NServiceBusInstaller: IWindsorInstaller {
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
        Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputQueue"])
            .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .UnicastBus()
                .SendOnly();
    }
}
```

The AppSettings key is the input queue in which the process host is also expecting messages, so as soon as it sends the message from the controller, it is placed in this queue and the host picks up on it immediately. Also by doing this it allows me to have the proper servers assigned to it as it is deployed to test and production.

Fortunately this was all the configuration I needed in the MVC application to work, I also had to put redirects for Windsor 3.1.